# PHP: please help using preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

Ex: `Found: 84 Displaying: 1 - 84`

I want to get out the number `84` between `Found` and `Displaying` with `preg_match` but I'm very bad at regular expression.

Do you know what good tutorial to learn regular expression? I can't find a good one on Google.

**Edit** *inserted from comments below*:

I just simplify my problem here. The real problem that I will find it in a full HTML page such as google search. You know what i mean right?

Comment: You must have found http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: _Now you have two problems..._ http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html :)

Answer (score 3):

If your input will always be in the same format, there's no need to use regular expressions.  Instead, just split the string on spaces:

```
// explode() on spaces, returning at most 2 array elements.
$parts = explode(" ", "Found: 84 Displaying: 1 - 84", 2);
echo $parts[1];
```

**Update** If you really really really want to use `preg_match()` for this, here's how. This is not recommended for an application this simple though.

```
// Array will hold matched results
$matches = array();

$input = "Found: 84 Displaying: 1 - 84";

// Your regex will match the pattern ([0-9]+) (one or more digits, between Found and Displaying
$result = preg_match("/^Found: ([0-9]+) Displaying/", $input, $matches);

// See what's inside your $matches array
print_r($matches);

// The number you want should be in $matches[1], the first subgroup captured
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: Off topic: I feel a lot of the "regex" questions could be adequately answered by splitting and finding the result.

Comment: great idea but i still want to know how to use preg_match too :-) Thanks.

Comment: @JaredFarrish If I had a dollar for every time I answered `explode()` to a regex question... (I do have 10-20 rep for each, but it's not the same :) )

Comment: @Michael is correct that if the input is always the same you don't need to do the overhead of using `preg_match()`.  Heck you could also use `trim(substr($str, 6, 4))` if the number is between 10 and 999.

Comment: @Quy Ok, see above. I've given you enough rope to hang yourself :)

Comment: Thanks all. I just simplify my problem here. The real problem that I will find it in a full HTML page such as google search. You know what i mean right?

Comment: @Quy that changes your question entirely.  Regular expressions should not be used to parse HTML. You need to use an HTML parsing library, DOMDocument, SimpleXML, or other.

Answer (score 1):

Fairly simple regex, I included PHP code that uses it:

```
<?php
preg_match("/(\d+)/", "Found: 84 Displaying: 1 - 84", $matches);
//$matches[0] should have the first number, i.e. 84
echo $matches[0]; // outputs "84"
?>
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/ has some pretty good information about how to write regular expressions.

Edit: as mentioned, regular expressions are overkill in this case, tokenizing works fine.